# how to access validation error property name in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, php-7.2

I have from in Laravel and I try to get validate it and see errors for each input, I already loop through `$error->all()` but I need to show the errors of each input under it and I use this code `$errors->has('password')` to show input have an error but I need to show message too.
I get `print_r($errors)` and It return this:

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object
(
    [bags:protected] => Array
        (
            [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object
                (
                    [messages:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [firstName] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => The first name field is required.
                                )

                            [lastName] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => The last name field is required.
                                )

                            [email] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => The email must be a valid email address.
                                    [1] => The email field is required.
                                )

                            [password] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => The password field is required.
                                )

                            [password_confirmation] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => The password confirmation field is required.
                                )

                        )

                    [format:protected] => :message
                )

        )

)
```

My problem is I can't how can access the messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS per Laravel Documentation you can use `@error` directive to achieve the same

> The `$errors` variable is bound to the view by the
>   `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware`, which is
>   provided by the web `middleware` group. When this middleware is applied
>   an $errors variable will always be available in your views, allowing
>   you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and
>   can be safely used.

for e.g

```
<label for="title">Post Title</label>

<input id="title" type="text" class="@error('title') is-invalid @enderror">

@error('title')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

[Laravel -> Validation -> Displaying The Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: welcome. Keep learning.. And do not forget to accept & upvote the answer :)